# Forcing use of transactions with ORMLite for Java

Tags: java, sqlite, ormlite

I have a program that is performing a low number of inserts (probably around 3000) into a local SQLite database, but with all raw db access wrapped by ORMLite. My problem is that the insertion rate is very low, something around 25 inserts per second. Another StackOverflow question clued me into forcing the code to use transactions, so I read the ORMLite docs.

Following the ORMLite documentation, I changed the code to the following:

```
        // Wrap all the inserts in a batch for increased speed.
        Section.getDao().callBatchTasks(
            new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    int currFileNum = 0;

                    // For each file, extract its sections.
                    for (HtmlFile file : files) {
                        String sectionString = file.getTitle();
                        String[] path = StringUtils.split(sectionString, ",");
                        Section.createFromPath(path, file.getId()); // Performs 1-5 Section.create() statements for each html file processed.
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

This code does not in fact affect insertion speed. I also tried using the `TransactionManager.callInTransaction()` code, also according to the ORMLite docs, but this did nothing at all to increase speed either.

Comment: The problem with ORMLite is that it wraps all JDBC calls in its own abstraction layer, and doesn't give access to lower-level methods like setAutoCommit(). That's why the ORMLite guys came up with the `callBatchTasks()` hack. The rest of my code, what little there is of it, does nothing more complex or time consuming than split a string into parts and query the database for things (Sections) matching those parts.

Comment: ORMLite certainly does give access to `dao.setAutoCommit(boolean)`.  It's in the `DAO` interface and `BaseDaoImpl` class.  http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)

Comment: @Gray, thanks for the feedback. I've run some tests and the basic problem is with SQLite itself (as it runs on my machine)... it's really slow on reads (a couple seconds for ~700 records) and writing 1000 records with an integer and a varchar field takes around 4-5 seconds, even with transactions used). So the problem is with my machine, probably disk IO, not with ORMLite.

Comment: Glad to hear it Erik.  With reads, maybe you are missing some indexes?  For writes, turning off auto-commit should give you a performance boost.

Comment: @Gray, I've given up on SQLite and have migrated to MySQL. Much faster! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the insertion rate is very low, something around 25 inserts per second.

So you are saying that you go to add 3000 records to a SQLIte database and it is taking 2 minutes to do so? That's really slow. Are you sure there's not something else taking time? Have you tried commenting out the database calls and checking the performance?

Instead of doing each block in a transaction you could try turning off auto-commit before the 3000 and turn it on afterwards.  Something like the following:

```
try {
   dao.setAutoCommit(false);
   ...
   insertBunchOfEntries();
   ...
} finally {
   dao.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```